# Possible to represent composite primary keys in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a table structure like so

```
+--------------+  +------------+  +--------------+  +-----------------+
| ships        |  | ship_types |  | ship_slots   |  | ship_components |
+--------------+  +------------+  +--------------+  +-----------------+
| id           |  | id         |  | id           |  | ship_id         |
| user_id      |  +------------+  | ship_type_id |  | ship_slot_id    |
| ship_type_id |                  +--------------+  +-----------------+
+--------------+  

ship_types hasMany ships
ship_types hasMany ship_slots
ships hasMany ship_components
ship_slots hasMany ship_components
```

When I do something like

```
ship->find(all, user_id = xyz)
```

I get

```
[0] =>
    Ship =>
        id 1
    ShipType =>
        ShipSlot =>
            [0] =>
                ShipComponent =>
                    [0] => ship_id 1
                    [1] => ship_id 2
            [1] => ...
[1] =>
    Ship =>
        id 2
    ShipType =>
        ShipSlot =>
            [0] =>
                ShipComponent =>
                    [0] => ship_id 1
                    [1] => ship_id 2
            [1] => ...
```

What Id like to have is

```
(ships + ship_slots) hasOne ship_components
```

The ship_id and ship_slot_id form a primary key for ship components. How do I set up the model associations so that the ship_slots will only associate to ship_components that have the ship_id of the parent ship.

```
select *
from ships
inner join ship_types on ship_types.id = ships.ship_type_id
left join ship_slots on ship_slots.ship_type_id = ship_types.id
left join ship_components on ship_components.ship_id = ships.id and ship_components.ship_slot_id = ship_slots.id
where ships.user_id = 5
```